# Cannot create a bucket in google cloud with the name even if i have deleted the previous one?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I created a bucket with my domain name in google cloud to host my static website there. I deleted it for some reason and now iam not able to create a same named bucket. Is there any thing i cannot do that again. Then is there any way i can create bucket to point my website.

Comment: What error are you receiving when you try to create the bucket?

Comment: It is alerting me that the bucket name is already used and you cannot create it with the same name.

Comment: @jterrace https://storage.googleapis.com/mintjava/Screen%20Shot%202016-06-14%20at%207.16.53%20AM.png

Comment: Are you sure you don't still have the bucket in another project?

Comment: Yes iam very sure that i dont have that bucket in my account....! i dont know why i cant create that bucket again....! @jterrace

Comment: @jterrace is there any support where i can raise my tickets on this. Is it possible to create a bucket in google cloud with the same name of one we deleted it. Is there any good tutorial where i can know all the in and out of google storage!

Comment: You can recreate a bucket after it's been deleted, but since buckets are in a global namespace, anyone can create a bucket with that name. However, if you're using a domain-named bucket, the creator has to prove ownership of the bucket. So it must exist under a project that verified ownership of the domain.

Comment: Iam the owner of the domain and i have already verified the domain ownership and also i created that bucket name once successfully. The second time iam not able to create it. (I shouldn't have deleted it.) Is there any way i can raise a ticket on this.

Comment: If you're seeing that message, the bucket definitely exists. Can you try accessing it with gsutil?